# Problematic design modifiying/accessing information of a derived class using the base object

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, derived

My problem is the following:

```
int main()
{
    Base* derivedobject = new Derived1();
    derivedobject->GetProperties()-> ???

return 0;
}

//********************
// BaseClass.h
//********************
struct PropertyStruct
{
    int x;
};

class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    ~Base();

    virtual PropertyStruct GetProperties() = 0;

private:
};

//********************
// DerivedClass1.h
//********************
struct PropertyStruct
{
    int y;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1();
    ~Derived1();

    PropertyStruct GetProperties() { return myOwnDifferentProperties; };

private:

};

//********************
// DerivedClass2.h
//********************
struct PropertyStruct
{
    float z;
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2();
    ~Derived2();

    PropertyStruct GetProperties() { return myOwnDifferentProperties };

private:

};
```

If I do it like that I'm going to get an error saying that PropertyStruct is a redefinition. If I use a namespace or rename the struct inside the derived class I am then going to get an error telling me that the return type is not the same as defined by Base.
If I define the virtual functions return type as a pointer it compiles, though the next problem when accessing the function "GetProperties" from the main method (in this example) the base object does not know what variables are inside the struct of the derived class.

Is there any way I can realize this ?
That I can get the different properties of each derived object but using the base class object ?

Comment: You can establish the base-derived relationship between two `PropertyStruct` with different names.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, there are ways to achieve your goals here but ultimately you will find yourself writing code like the following:

```
    Base * object = ...;

    if object is Derived1 then
      get Property1 and do something with it
    else if object is Derived2 then
      get Property2 and do something with it
```

This is an anti-pattern in object-oriented programming.  You already have a class hierarchy to represent the differences between the various derived types.  Rather than extracting the data from your objects and processing it externally, consider adding a virtual function to the base class and letting the derived classes do the processing.

```
class Base
{
public:

    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : Base
{
public:

    void DoSomething()
    {
        // use myOwnDifferentProperties as necessary
    }

private:

    PropertyStruct myOwnDifferentProperties;
};
```

If it's not appropriate to put the required processing in the derived classes (i.e. if it would introduce unwanted responsibilities) then you may want to consider the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) as a way to extend the functionality of your hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Since template functions cannot be virtual you can use hierarchy of your properties. It's only one way, no other ways. For get elements of derived Properties you should use virtual getter functions.

```
struct BaseProp
{
    virtual ~BaseProp() { }
    virtual boost::any getProperty() const = 0;
};

struct PropertyStruct : BaseProp
{
    boost::any getProperty() const { return x; }
private:
    int x;
};

struct PropertyStruct2 : BaseProp
{
    boost::any getProperty() const { return y; }
private:
    float y;
};

class Base
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<BaseProp> GetProperties() const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() { }
}

class Derived
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<BaseProp> GetProperties() const { return new PropertyStruct(); }
};

class Derived2
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<BaseProp> GetProperties() const { return new PropertyStruct2(); }
};
```

Comment: @Code-Guru No other ways to achieve goal, that want OP without deriving.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template class to do that:

```
struct PropertyStruct1 {
    float f;
};

struct PropertyStruct2 {
    int i;
};

template<class T>
class A{
public:
    T GetProperties() {return mProps;}

private:
    T mProps;   
};

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    A<PropertyStruct1> a1;
    int f = a1.GetProperties().f;
    A<PropertyStruct2> a2;
    int i = a2.GetProperties().i;
    return 0;
}
```